# it is possible get Salesforce ChangeSet components throw API or Apex?

Tags: change-set, ci

I just wondering about the way to retrieve information from a changeset, I want to use it for source control proposes. Someone know a way to do this?

Comment: yes this is possible! check out https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/169071/594