# Add custom field to change set using Metadata API

Tags: metadata, change-set

I'm wondering if we can add a custom field or any other component to change set using Metadata API?

Comment: Consider a similar conversation at this thread:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/114909/salesforce-metadata-api-tooling-api-to-build-changesets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no API for modifying a change set, as far as I can tell. If you want to use something more portable, consider creating a Package instead. You can use packages in the Metadata API.